# How to generate Random coordinates within a circle with specified radius?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to generate random coordinates (lat,long) that lies within a circle with 5 kilometer radius where center point is located at some coordinates (x, y). I am trying to code this in ruby and I'm using the method but somehow i get the results that are NOT within specified 5 km radius.

```
def location(lat, lng, max_dist_meters)
  max_radius = Math.sqrt((max_dist_meters ** 2) / 2.0)
  lat_offset = rand(10 ** (Math.log10(max_radius / 1.11)-5))
  lng_offset = rand(10 ** (Math.log10(max_radius / 1.11)-5))
  lat += [1,-1].sample * lat_offset
  lng += [1,-1].sample * lng_offset
  lat = [[-90, lat].max, 90].min
  lng = [[-180, lng].max, 180].min
  [lat, lng]
end
```

Comment: Why don't you generate a random radius and angle and apply those to your center?

Comment: I don't need a random radius i need random coordinates within the circle

Comment: Yes you do need a random radius and angle. Cartesian `(x,y)` coordinates can also be represented as `(r, θ)` polar coordinates. You're working with a circle so polar coordinates are a natural fit.

Comment: @DenisS. Random coordinates within the circle will have a random distance from the center of the circle.  I'm sure that's what mu meant by "random radius".  Generating an angle to head out along, and a distance to go, is a very natural way to get points in a circle.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response, what should i change and add in the method above to get right result?

Comment: You need to define "random coordinates" more carefully. If the coordinates lie on a fixed grid, so that the distance between two adjacent coordinates (horizontal or vertical) is fixed, you cannot obtain those coordinates using an angle and distance. If you selected the closest "rectangular" coordinate to a given polar coordinate, that would heavily bias coordinates near the centre--that is, it would not be random. Please edit to clarify the layout of the coordinates.

Comment: Generating random radius with constant distribution will make the plot biased toward the center of the circle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Your code

```
max_radius = Math.sqrt((max_dist_meters ** 2) / 2.0)
```

This is just `max_dist_meters.abs / Math.sqrt(2)` or `max_dist_meters * 0.7071067811865475`.

```
10 ** (Math.log10(max_radius / 1.11)-5)
```

This can be written `9.00901E-6 * max_radius`, so it's `6.370325E−6 * max_dist_meters`.

```
rand(10 ** (Math.log10(max_radius / 1.11)-5))
```

Now for the fun part : `rand(x)` is just [`rand()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) if x is between `-1` and `1`. So if `max_dist_meters` is smaller than `1/6.370325E−6 ~ 156977.86`, all your 3 first lines do is :

```
lat_offset = rand()
lng_offset = rand()
```

So for `max_dist_meters = 5000`, your method will return a random point that could be 1° longitude and 1° latitude away. At most, it would be a bit more than 157km.

Worse, if `x` is between `156978` and `313955`, your code is equivalent to :

```
lat_offset = lng_offset = 0
```

Since Ruby 2.4

```
[[-90, lat].max, 90].min
```

can be written [`lat.clamp(-90, 90)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp)

## Possible solution

To get a uniform distribution of random points on the disk of radius `max_radius`, you need [a non-uniform distribution of random radii](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) :

```
def random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  r = max_radius * rand ** 0.5
  theta = rand * 2 * Math::PI
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end
```

Here's a plot with a million random points :

[image: Uniform distribution]

Here's the same plot with @Schwern's code :

[image: Non-uniform distribution]

Once you have this method, you can apply some basic math to convert meters to latitude and longitude. Just remember that 1° of latitude is always 111.2km but 1° of longitude is 111.2km at the equator but 0km at the poles :

```
def random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  r = max_radius * rand**0.5
  theta = rand * 2 * Math::PI
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end

EarthRadius = 6371 # km
OneDegree = EarthRadius * 2 * Math::PI / 360 * 1000 # 1° latitude in meters

def random_location(lon, lat, max_radius)
  dx, dy = random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  random_lat = lat + dy / OneDegree
  random_lon = lon + dx / ( OneDegree * Math::cos(lat * Math::PI / 180) )
  [random_lon, random_lat]
end
```

For this kind of calculation, there's no need to install a 800-pound GIS gorilla.

A few points:

- We usually talk about latitude first and longitude second, but in GIS, it's usually `lon` first because `x` comes before `y`.
- `cos(lat)` is considered to be constant so `max_radius` shouldn't be too big. A few dozens kilometers shouldn't pose any problem. The shape of a disk on a sphere becomes [weird with a large radius](https://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm?clat=47.21786877398939&clng=-1.5499520301818848&r=14000&lc=FFFFFF&lw=1&fc=00FF00&fs=true).
- Don't use this method too close to the poles, you'd get arbitrarily large coordinates otherwise.

To test it, let's create random points on 200km disks at different locations:

```
10_000.times do
  [-120, -60, 0, 60, 120].each do |lon|
    [-85, -45, 0, 45, 85].each do |lat|
      puts random_location(lon, lat, 200_000).join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

With gnuplot, here's the resulting diagram:

[image]

Yay! I just reinvented [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix), 150 years too late :

[image]

Comment: I like that you addressed the conversion back to lat/long, nice work!

Comment: What is the theta for in this formula? I tried googling what 2pi is for and it just led me down to a rabbit hole. Also include r as well.

Comment: @doesnotmatter it's the angle in polar coordinates : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system.

Comment: Anyone has an idea how this could look like in C# 'def random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  r = max_radius * rand ** 0.5
  theta = rand * 2 * Math::PI
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end'

Comment: @STORM: [Here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpVbPp) my first C# program ever. From what I understood, it should give the same random distribution as my Ruby code above.

Answer (score 3):

```
def location(x_origin, y_origin, radius)
  x_offset, y_offset = nil, nil
  rad = radius.to_f

  begin
    x_offset = rand(-rad..rad)
    y_offset = rand(-rad..rad)
  end until Math.hypot(x_offset, y_offset) < radius

  [x_origin + x_offset, y_origin + y_offset] 
end
```

Comment: Excellent, I can't think of any other way to ensure randomness (though @pjs has suggest a way).

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're equating randomness with uniformity.  The alternate solution is certainly random, just not uniform.

Comment: @Mori is radius passed in meters in the function above?

Comment: @DenisS., this method doesn't change the unit, so will return whatever is given, cubits, meters, light years, whatever.

Comment: @pjs, if there are `N` coordinates within the circle (computing limitations make the number finite) we want the probability of any one being chosen to be `1/N`. N'est-ce pas?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, you're thinking of discrete uniformity. Mathematically, we're not picking items from a fixed set of N, we're drawing samples over a continuous space, so the number of possible points is (theoretically) infinite.  (Okay, computationally it's not infinite, but it's very large...) Uniformity in one dimension means that the expected number of points is proportional to the length of the interval; in two dimension, uniformity means proportional to area; in three dimensions, proportional to volume; etc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Please take a look at my answer if you want some more information about uniformity.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's not completely clear that it's less efficient.  This is comparable to using [Marsaglia's "polar method" vs a Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform) to generate Gaussian random variables.  The acceptance/rejection based polar method was found to often outperform Box-Muller, much to many people's surprise, because it avoided the sine/cosine trigonometric evaluations which are computationally expensive on many machines.

Comment: @pjs: Very interesting, thanks. To generate many points, I suppose it'd be better to compare `x**2+y**2 < radius_squared`

Comment: @EricDuminil Correct.  Even better to compare `x*x + y*y < radius_squared`, unless your optimizing compiler is clever enough to realize it doesn't need to take logs, multiply, and exponentiate to calculate a square.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest generating a random radius and a random angle. Then you can use those to generate a coordinate with `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`.

```
def location(max_radius)
    # 0 to max radius.
    # Using a range ensures max_radius is included.
    radius = Random.rand(0.0..max_radius)

    # 0 to 2 Pi excluding 2 Pi because that's just 0.
    # Using Random.rand() because Kernel#rand() does not honor floats.
    radians = Random.rand(2 * Math::PI)

    # Math.cos/sin work in radians, not degrees.
    x = radius * Math.cos(radians)
    y = radius * Math.sin(radians)

    return [x, y]
end
```

I'll leave converting this to lat/long and adding a center for you.

Really what I'd suggest is finding a geometry library that supports operations like "give me a random point inside this shape", "is this point inside this shape" and will do lat/long conversions for you because this stuff is very easy to get subtly wrong.

You could build on top of the [Ruby geometry gem](https://github.com/bfoz/geometry) which provides you with classes for basic shapes. Or if your data is in a database, many support geometric types like [PostgreSQL's geometry types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-geometry.html), the more powerful [PostGIS add-on](http://postgis.net/), or even [MySQL has spatial data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: That produces points which are concentrated near the center of the circle.  If you want the points to be uniformly distributed over the circle, replace `radius = rand(0.0..max_radius)` with `radius = max_radius * Math.sqrt(rand)`.

Comment: @pjs Thanks! Could you explain a bit more about why that works or link to something that does?

Comment: @pjs, could you provide a proof that the adjustment you suggest produces a random selection? It does seem plausible.

Comment: You want the number of points to be proportional to the area, and the area of a circle grows as radius**2, so a square root correction adjusts things properly.

Comment: If you don't trust my handwaving intuitive area-based argument, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html.  I'd argue that the creators of Mathematica have street cred on this.

Comment: Also see http://narimanfarsad.blogspot.com/2012/11/uniformly-distributed-points-inside.html for a more rigorous proof.

Comment: @pjs: You're totally right. I've added an answer which uses this method of generation.

Comment: @Schwern: I'd say that a GIS is overkill for this specific task. It's much more important to use a correct random point generation.

Comment: @Schwern: Also, this "weird behaviour" is described in the [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) : `rand(1.9)` is interpreted as `rand(1)`, which is always `0`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ahh, I confused `Random.rand` with `Kernel#rand`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem that does what you need.

https://github.com/sauloperez/random-location

Just install the gem and require it on your code:

```
gem install random-location
require 'random-location'
RandomLocation.near_by(41.38506, 2.17340, 10000)
```