# Generate random coordinates outside and within a given radius from origin

Tags: ruby, random, coordinates, polar-coordinates

I need to generate a spec for my search engine to test that, when I specify an origin point and a radius, results beyond results of my source origin are not included in the response, while radius within the given radius in kilometers are included.

Given the origin and the radius, I want to test two "extreme" cases where I create two test data points,

- one within: on the exact radius minus an epsilon (radius - e away from the origin)
- one outside: on the exact radius plus an epsilon (radius + e away from origin)

For instance if my radius is 10km, I'd like to generate a point 10.1km away and 9.9 km away from the source.

Then, I want to run many tests where I pick random points on earth (either within or outside the radius) to check that all corner cases are handled well by my search engine

I am checking the code actually works with `Geocoder.distance_between`

```
before do
  # Ensure our example is correct
  expect(
    Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(origin, point_outside_radius_of_origin)
  ).to be > radius_in_km

  expect(
    Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(origin, point_within_radius_of_origin)
  ).to be < radius_in_km
end
```

For instance the following fixed example passes

Using a fixed example of Paris

```
let(:origin) { [48.856614, 2.3522219] } # Geocoder.coordinates('Paris')
let(:radius_in_km) { 10 }
let(:point_within_radius_of_origin) { [48.801148, 2.429443] } # Geocoder.coordinates('Maisons-Alfort')
let(:point_outside_radius_of_origin) { [48.790367, 2.455572] } # Geocoder.coordinates('Créteil')
```

---

So I'm trying to implement function to generate random points from an origin.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202522/2832282 I was somehow able to generate a point within the given radius : (this function seems to work perfectly)

```
# Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202522/2832282
#
# @param lon [Float]
# @param lat [Float]
# @param max_radius [FLoat] in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>] [Lng, lat]
def random_point_within_radius_of_origin(lng:, lat:, max_radius:)
  dx, dy = Utility.random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  random_lat = lat + dy / OneDegree
  random_lng = lng + dx / ( OneDegree * Math::cos(lat * Math::PI / 180) )
  [random_lng, random_lat]
end
# @param max_radius [Float] Distance in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>]
def random_point_in_disk(max_radius)
  r = max_radius * rand**0.5
  theta = rand * 2 * Math::PI
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end
```

I need **to implement the function below to generate a random point outside the radius from the origin** (I don't really care whether uniformly distributed or not) outside the given disk. I guess I could generate a fake point and retry until I hit the goal off.

*Note that if you have some code that works without specifying a max_radius this is even better (I basically just want to exclude the coordinates generated by the aforementionned function)*

```
# @param lon [Float] Longitude of origin
# @param lat [Float] Latitude of origin
# @param max_radius [FLoat] Max radius from origin in km
# @param min_radius [FLoat] Min radius from origin in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>] [Lng, lat] of some random point between min_radius and max_radius of origin
def random_point_within_radius_band_of_origin(lng:, lat:, max_radius:, min_radius:)
  # What this SO Question is about
end
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5822

Answer (score 1):

If you need code to generate uniform random point in the radial band, here it is (untested!)

```
# @param min_radius [Float] Minimum radius, in km
# @param max_radius [Float] Maximum radius, in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>]
def random_point_in_band(min_radius, max_radius)
  r     = min_radius + (max_radius - min_radius) *  Math.sqrt(rand)
  theta = 2.0 * Math::PI * rand
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end
```

Comment: I need this but from an origin point in longitude/latitude degree format `[origin_longitude, origin_latitude]`

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris So problem is with function `random_point_within_radius_of_origin`, the translation part? If you add to `random_point_within_radius_of_origin` parameter `min_radius` and call inside  `random_point_in_band`, will it work or there is still a problem?

Comment: I edited my answer. My first function `random_point_within_radius_of_origin` is fine, what I need to implement `random_point_within_radius_band_of_origin`. Basically I need to understand how I can add your function's return to my origin point. I'm not sure I can use the same trick as in the original function `lat + dy / OneDegree`, `lng + dx / ( OneDegree * Math::cos(lat * Math::PI / 180) )`. Or can I ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris I'm not that familiar with mapping from local coordinates to `(lng,lat)`. Could you try the same trick and just plot, say, 1000 sampled points?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris Really you have two questions in one. First is to sample locally point in a radial band. Second is mapping of sampling centre from (0,0) to some global position (lat,long). I would advice to ask second question separately, because they don't have much in common

Comment: I disagree with you on that. My question is about generating coordinates. Sampling locally a point in a radial band and moving that from an origin) is only one solution. Another solution might be to generate random coordinates, evaluate their distance from the origin point, and retry until we get one coordinate that is far enough from the origin coordinates, and that would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is straight forward to combine [Severin's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208240/8416610) for generating a random point within a band with the code from `random_point_within_radius_of_origin`:

```
# @param min_radius [Float] Minimum radius, in km
# @param max_radius [Float] Maximum radius, in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>]
def random_point_in_band(min_radius, max_radius)
  r     = min_radius + (max_radius - min_radius) *  Math.sqrt(rand)
  theta = 2.0 * Math::PI * rand
  [r * Math.cos(theta), r * Math.sin(theta)]
end

EarthRadius = 6371 # km
OneDegree = EarthRadius * 2 * Math::PI / 360 * 1000 # 1° latitude in meters

# @param lon [Float] Longitude of origin
# @param lat [Float] Latitude of origin
# @param max_radius [FLoat] Max radius from origin in km
# @param min_radius [FLoat] Min radius from origin in km
#
# @return [Pair<Float>] [Lng, lat] of some random point between min_radius and max_radius of origin
def random_point_within_radius_band_of_origin(lng:, lat:, max_radius:, min_radius:)
  dx, dy = random_point_in_band(min_radius, max_radius)
  random_lat = lat + dy / OneDegree
  random_lng = lng + dx / ( OneDegree * Math::cos(lat * Math::PI / 180) )
  [random_lng, random_lat]
end
```